# ØMQ N-to-M message queue

Tags: zeromq

I am considering the feasibility that if we can replace our message-queue-middleware with ØMQ.

I have two set of servers.
The first set of the servers,  they don't talk to another server from the same set, they only append the requests into specific message-queue.

The 2nd set of the servers, they don't talk to another server from the same set, they only receive the requests from specific message-queue to handle the requests.

It looks like a producer-consumer model.

And I think it can be replaced by the ØMQ's freelance pattern [http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#Brokerless-Reliability-Freelance-Pattern](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page%3aall#Brokerless-Reliability-Freelance-Pattern).

But the questions are:

How to support dynamic discovery for both server & clients?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to support dynamic discovery for both server & clients?

There are probably a hundred ways you could implement that, and greatly depend on your situation. If all the servers will always be on the same LAN you could bootstrap using the broadcast address on the local network and ask all responders who they are. Quick and dirty.

I would personally implement a bootstrap service that everyone knows about. They all can ask this always-available service for who is 'online' for the type of server they're after.

Answer (score 0):

Another option, you could also use pub-sub. This would require a central publisher. newly connecting nodes would notify the publisher who would notify all other nodes of the new join, possibly including the new nodes ID, ip:port (if desired) etc. All nodes will still be able to communicate if the publisher crashes since its only used for global notifications, and a backup publisher could be used to make the system failsafe. Each node can also send heartbeats to publisher, with publisher notifying all other nodes when a node leaves/crashes.